# How is adamantium made

Tags: marvel, x-men, adamantium

I very know little of it but I know it's extracted from a Meteorite in *X-men Origins* and was used in wolverine. I also read some comments and statements that other mutants use it too. How does the one who crafts and embeds this unique metal have enough supplies? Do we need little ore and plenty of finished goods?

Follow up question: If it's indestructible, how can we forge it, liquefy it. After it has cooled down and solidified, could it still be reprocessed like other metals?

Comment: Take a look at the [Marvel Wiki page on Adamantium](http://marvel.wikia.com/Adamantium); all your questions will be answered there :) - I'm pointing you there instead of answering directly, partially because there are multiple variants.

Comment: it did thanks!!

Comment: It is probably made by refining unobtanium. :)

Comment: Unobtanium mixed with cavorite, to make it lightweight.

Comment: plenty of metals in marvel universe.

Comment: Might be a little mithril in it too. It has that nice shine.

Comment: There are a bunch of different kinds. Which do you mean?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

http://marvel.wikia.com/Adamantium on Adamantium as stated by Keith

Answer (score -5):

Adamantium is made from iron that is chemically mixed with other metals and elements ina pressurized furance to make it super hard and super strong.